# Basic authentication error with urllib2 since python 2.7 update

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, urllib2, basic-authentication

This piece of python code worked fine an hour ago, before I ran an apt-get upgrade on my raspberry pi.

This is now my python version: Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04)

```
import urllib, urllib2
from PIL import Image

URL="http://server.local/picture.jpg"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encodestring('Guess:Thepassword')}
req = urllib2.Request(URL, None, headers)
img=Image.open(urllib2.urlopen(req,timeout=1))
```

But now I get this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1017, in putheader
raise ValueError('Invalid header value %r' % (one_value,))
ValueError: Invalid header value 'Basic TGlvbjpSdW5SYWJiaXRSdW4=\n'
```

I assume something has changed, but can't figure out what..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a new line character `\n` at the end of your header. Instead of using `base64.encodestring`, use `base64.b64encode`.

I don't think this has anything to do with an update to Python, since this behaviour has been there since the base64 module was included back in Python 2.4 (see the bolded text):

> Encode the string s, which can contain arbitrary binary data, and
>   return a string containing one or more lines of base64-encoded data.
>   encodestring() returns a string containing one or more lines of
>   base64-encoded data **always including an extra trailing newline ('\n')**.

Comment: That did it, thank you. I am100% certain however it was caused somehow by the update, as I have older versions of the python script to check and run, where the code is identical as it was before AND I have another raspberry pi, not yet apt-get upgraded, where it does run without the error.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I believe the change in functionality can be traced to this security update:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3:

```
SECURITY UPDATE: CRLF injection vulnerability in the
HTTPConnection.putheader
- debian/patches/CVE-2016-5699.patch: disallow newlines in
  putheader() arguments when not followed by spaces or tabs in
  Lib/httplib.py, add tests in Lib/test/test_httplib.py
- CVE-2016-5699
```